# I have a dropdown from database and want to open new html/jsp pages on clicking respective dropdowns by using jQuery

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

This is my `java` code which is retrieving dropdown from database; I have the `$dropdown` in one list and all should redirect me to new `html/jsp` page

```
public List<String> getmenu1() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        con = DBConnection.createConnection();
        statement = con.createStatement();

        try {

            ResultSet resultSet = statement
                    .executeQuery("select mt_menus_vcmenuname from mt_menus where mt_menus_vcmenucode='400'");
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                list.add(resultSet.getString("mt_menus_vcmenuname"));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return list;
    }
```

This is my `jsp` page which shows the dropdown what I am trying to do is to open a new pages on clicking diff dropdowns

```
                <!-- dropdown menus for setup -->
            </c:forEach>
            <div id="drop" class="dropdown-menu">

                <c:forEach var="item" items="${obj.menu1}">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> ${item}</a>
                </c:forEach>
            </div></li>
```

Comment: When you say open a new page, do you mean a new page in your browser? If so, add `target="_blank"` to your a tag. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp

Comment: Add a change event (`jQuery or Javascript`) for the drop down and implement your logic there.

Comment: yes that means a new page in my prowser which is already in my project

Comment: i have more that one dropdown which is comming from database and i have to link all of them to diff pages when the dropdown will clicked a page should open for that dropdown simillarly for others also